# Image ratio check at runtime (Performance issue) - android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an image picker application that selects images from gallery. If the image doesn't have a particular width/height ratio I display a small warning symbol on top of the image.

In my **XML View File** I have two `ImageView` views. It is below:

**view.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgQueue"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/wrongimagesign"
        android:src="@drawable/error"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgQueue"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imgQueue"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imgQueue"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The images are displayed in a `gridview` so in my adapter i have this code:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("file://" + image.cardPath, imgQueue);

**Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImageSync("file://" + image.cardPath, Utility.displayImageOptions);**

wrongImageSign.setVisibility(imageRatioIsBad(bitmap) ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
```

The problem is that since i am loading the bitmap the performance is very slow (it takes too long to load the image and display the warning sign). Is there a way to improve the performance.

Comment: what you mean with too long, is the UI not responding, or its just too long until you see the image in the UI ? also to get an idea why you image loading takes long, you should present the code that loads the image.

Comment: @fmt.Println.MKO it takes too long until i see the image in the UI

Comment: show your code, how you load the image, and does it happens to all images? maybe your image is very big ?

Comment: I am using the library `nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader` to load the image. So `ImageLoader...loadImageSync` is loading the bitmap. My images are normal image which you capture with a samsung galaxy s3

Comment: have a look at there docs: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Configuration, I suppose you don't use a cache, and you load the whole image into your gridview, instead load a small version (scaled) version. which is also stored in file cache